# solve below in finding the length of xml data in the delimited file, and also i want to parse the 7th column in the record

Tags: scala

```
  val result = data.map(line => {
  val event=line.split("\\^")

  val x=Integer.parseInt(event(2))
  val y=event(5)
  val z=event(4)

  (x,y,z,event)

}).filter(line => {
  var flag=false
  if(line._1==100 && line._4.length==7 && line._2.nonEmpty /*&& line._3.length()==8*/)
    flag =true
    flag
}).map(line => {
  (line._1,line._3)
})

println(result.count())
result.foreach(println)
```

Note: I am getting error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5`

Comment: 1234^1^100^2015-06-05 22:35:21.543^
<d
  <nv n="a" v="2314" />
  <nv n="b" v="1234" />
  <nv n="c" v="1366" />
  <nv n="d" v="24375" />
  <nv n="e" v="True" />
  <nv n="f" v="4123" />
  <nv n="g" v="value of g" />
  <nv n="h" v="1423" />
</d>  
^0122648d-4352-4eec-9327-effae0c34ef2^2016060601    -- It is one record, where i want to parsexml column = 8 and value of c in the record with name and value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 0):

> > I am getting error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5`

*Isn't the error message clear enough to understand what is the mistake?* The error message is suggesting you that **there are not enough `^` character in some of the lines you are splitting to get 5th array**.

**Solution**

Use `Try` *wherever you suspect there won't be enough data*  as

```
import scala.util.Try
val y=Try(event(5)) getOrElse("")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ramesh Maharajan, I am able to solve with your solution

Comment: if the answer helped you then you should consider accepting and upvote if possible. @MaheshYadav